# Android: Can't prevent Maps work

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Activity where I want to use:

```
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
public class BankoTinklasMap extends MapActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.banko_tinklas_map);

    MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

I added activity to Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="lt.balticamadeus.babank"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>
<application

    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <!-- other activities goes here. They work fine -->
    <activity
        android:name="BankoTinklasMap"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

xml layout file looks like in android tutorial:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="My_Real_api_key_but_i_dont_show_you"
/>
```

Maps library exist, because target is Google API. So eclipse and compilation doesn't show any problem.
Problem is that I get this error while trying to launch Activity at run time:

```
 04-17 08:51:07.637: E/AndroidRuntime(25080): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: lt.balticamadeus.babank.BankoTinklasMap
```

So question is: What I missed, so I can launch this activity right way?

Comment: where is main.xml or the layout file where you have the map?

Comment: Can you please provide the error details - stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do following changes

```
<activity
    android:name="your package name.BankoTinklasMap"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

& put below line inside your application tag

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Let me know if it's still not working............

Comment: Only thing you are missing is '<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> ' this line must be in Application tag